# Accessing Firefox add-ons particularly multifox from javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Firstly, is it possible to access Firefox add-ons/extensions from JavaScript? If so, how to execute Multifox commands from JavaScript?

I'm trying to isolate sessions in Firefox so that more than one user can login to a website simultaneously. I found multifox as a solution but I don't know how to launch page with multifox support. Let me know if better option is available.

Comment: you aren't clear what you want.  Do you want a firefox extension that leverages multifox functionality or javascript in a web page that can leverage it, if its installed?

Comment: i'm trying to solve cookie sharing problem with firefox.I found multifox as a solution but i dont know how to call multifox commands from javascript to invoke multifox.Infact i couldnt find the multifox commands.